# How to show the username of the last svn commit in browser?

Tags: svn

Since last few days i have been working on [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and now i have successfully setup the SVN server for my local network. When we are opening any repository in browser then there is last revision number is shown on top of the page. so what i want to do is.

How do i show the name of last commit on browser? i an able to find this name using command but is there any way to show that user name of browser ?

Any suggestion and advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What svn server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a separate SVN Browser, like [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/features/) or [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/).

In addition you get features like history and diff.